# Showing a view controller from an OpenGL view

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, opengl

I have created an iPhone application based on an OpenGL view. Now I 
would like to show a "settings" form. Since my code runs in UIView, I have no pushViewController. How do I show a view controller on screen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in one of two ways:

- You can create a new view hierarchy, and then add it as a subview of your UIWindow when you want to show preferences. When you're done with your prefs, you can animate it out and then remove it as a subview.
- You can switch to a UINavigationController/UIVIewController based hierarchy, and hook your current OpenGL/UIView to a UIViewController's view outlet. Then you can use all the regular UINavigationController based navigation stuff.